# In JavaCard, the simulator can use PCSC interface to communicate?

Tags: sdk, applet, javacard, apdu, pcsc

I wrote an Applet, but don't want to send and receive APDU by SDK, could you tell me how should do?
The simulator in javacard development kit can communicate with PCSC interface?

I have used the JCOP tool and oracle's JavaCard SDK. Both of them cannot communicate with PCSC interface.They can only communicate with simulator through the IDE itself.

Comment: @vojta   I have used the JCOP tool and oracle's JavaCard SDK. Both of them cannot communicate with PCSC interface.They can only communicate with simulator through the IDE itself.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of softwares. here is one of them : https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki     moreover, your reader doesn't have any tool to work with it? What kind of reader do you use?

Answer (score 5):

There is a development kits called JCIDE, used the concept of virtual card reader.  Through the virtual card reader, you can used a PC/SC compliant application to communicate with the SmartCard simulator.

The virtual card reader have supported a UMDF(User Mode Driver Framework) card-reader driver which connects to JCIDE to allow any PC/SC compliant application to send APDU to JCIDE and receive response from JCIDE.

For more information, you can download it from "http://javacos.com/developmentkit.php ".

Comment: I downloaded the  JCIDE, and installed, but I still don't know  how to use virtual  card reader.Can you tell me?

Comment: There is a  video about how to use virtual card reader, you can see it in  :  http://youtu.be/B4E75JT2RVo